# HTMLpurifier is stripping out tables. Anyone know why?

Tags: htmlpurifier

I have just downloaded HTML purifier in order to clean my wysigyg editor inputs but it seems to be stripping out tables.

If I input this text:

```
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: 150%; mso-outline-level: 3;"><span style='color: black; line-height: 150%; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'>Recruitment methods</span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><table style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; border-collapse: collapse; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-yfti-tbllook: 1184; mso-padding-alt: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font><tbody><tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 0; mso-yfti-firstrow: yes;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="37" style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; border: 1pt solid windowtext; border-image: none; width: 27.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal;"><span style='font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'><font size="3">No.</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font></td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="180" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 134.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="210" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 157.5pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="211" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 2.2in; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font></tr><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font><tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 1;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="37" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext; padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 27.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal;"><span style='font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'><font size="3">1</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font></td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="180" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 134.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="210" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 157.5pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><td width="211" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 2.2in; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font></tr><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font></tbody></table><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 10pt; text-align: center;"><span style='line-height: 115%; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'>&nbsp;</span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><p style="margin: 0in 0in 10pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><br>
```

I get this output:

```
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><p style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;line-height:150%;"><span style="color:#000000;line-height:150%;font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';font-size:12pt;">Recruitment methods</span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p align="center" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">No.</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p align="center" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">Method</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p align="center" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">Strengths</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p align="center" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">Weaknesses</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
 </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p align="center" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;text-align:center;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">1</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">Internal recruitment</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">Promotion</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3">Lateral transfer</font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><p style="margin:0in 0in 0pt;line-height:normal;"><span style="font-family:Arial, 'sans-serif';"><font size="3"> </font></span></p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
  </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3"> etc...
```

My setup looks like this:

```
require_once 'purify/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,span[style|class],a[href|title],abbr[title],acronym[title],b,strong,blockquote[cite],code,em,i,iframe[src|width|height],img[alt|title|class|src|height|width],h1,h2,h3,h3,ol,ul,li,table[class|style],tr,td,hr');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

I only added the HTML.Allowed line in order to try and specifically allow tables, but that didn't work. Does anyone have any idea why it is stripping out tables even though it shouldn't be?

Thanks

Comment: Is `table[class|style]` read as tables that have both attributes?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit odd - initially I thought maybe one of the `<font>` tags (an inline element) were surrounding a block-level element, thus forcing it to get stripped, and the error then cascading up from there, but after running the code through a basic (dumb) HTML formatter, it looks like they're all fairly self-contained.

But turning on Error Collection shows us what's going on. The trouble seems to be that despite being self-contained, HTML Purifier closes the `<table>` tag once it encounters the first `<font>`, it doesn't remove the `<font>` (as one might think):

> **Notice** *Line 7, Column 8:* **<table> started on line 6 auto-closed by <font>**
>
> **Error** *Line 10, Column 8:* **style attribute on <tr> removed**
>
> **Notice** *Line 11, Column 12:* **<tr> started on line 10 auto-closed by <font>**
>
> **Notice** *Line 11, Column 12:* **<tbody> started on line 9 auto-closed by <font>**
>
> **Warning** *Line 31, Column 8:* **Unnecessary </tr> tag removed**
>
> **Error** *Line 34, Column 8:* **style attribute on <tr> removed**
>
> **Notice** *Line 35, Column 12:* **<tr> started on line 34 auto-closed by <font>**
>
> **Warning** *Line 55, Column 8:* **Unnecessary </tr> tag removed**
>
> **Warning** *Line 59, Column 8:* **Unnecessary </tbody> tag removed**
>
> **Warning** *Line 60, Column 4:* **Unnecessary </table> tag removed**
>
> **Notice** *End of Document:* **<p> tag started on line 66 closed by end of document**
>
> **Warning** *End of Document:* **Contents of <div> node reorganized to enforce its content model**

That's the output of [the demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php) if you select **CollectErrors**: *Yes* and plug in the following HTML:

```
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font>
<p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: 150%; mso-outline-level: 3;"><span style='color: black; line-height: 150%; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'>Recruitment methods</span></p>
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font>
<table style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; border-collapse: collapse; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-yfti-tbllook: 1184; mso-padding-alt: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
    </font>
    <tbody>
    <tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 0; mso-yfti-firstrow: yes;">
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="37" style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; border: 1pt solid windowtext; border-image: none; width: 27.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">
            <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
            </font>
            <p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal;"><span style='font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'><font size="3">No.</font></span></p>
            <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
            </font>
        </td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="180" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 134.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="210" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 157.5pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="211" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: windowtext windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 2.2in; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
    </tr>
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
    </font>
    <tr style="mso-yfti-irow: 1;">
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="37" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext; padding: 0in 5.4pt; border-image: none; width: 27.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">
            <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
            </font>
            <p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; text-align: center; line-height: normal;"><span style='font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'><font size="3">1</font></span></p>
            <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
            </font>
        </td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="180" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 134.95pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="210" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 157.5pt; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
        <td width="211" style="border-width: 0px 1pt 1pt 0px; border-style: none solid solid none; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) windowtext windowtext rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; width: 2.2in; background-color: transparent; mso-border-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-left-alt: solid windowtext .5pt; mso-border-top-alt: solid windowtext .5pt;">&nbsp;</td>
        <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
        </font>
    </tr>
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
    </font><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
    </font>
    </tbody>
</table>
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font>
<p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 10pt; text-align: center;"><span style='line-height: 115%; font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 12pt; mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-bidi; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;'>&nbsp;</span></p>
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font>
<p style="margin: 0in 0in 10pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
</font><br>
```

There's [another thread on the HTML Purifier forum](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,5393,5411) that might make this a bit more understandable. Symptoms were described like this:

> When I try to purify this code:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr>
>     <td>
>       <li>fffff</li>
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```
>
> I get:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr>
>     <td>
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
>
> fffff
> ```

And (my, heh) response back then:

> I imagine what's happening is that HTML Purifier is detecting that <li> cannot be opened at that position - but rather than strip the <li> first, it auto-closes the other open tags at that point, resulting (initially) in:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr>
>     <td>
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> <li>fffff</li>
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```
>
> Then removing extraneous closing tags...
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr>
>     <td>
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> <li>fffff</li>
> ```
>
> And then stripping the <li>, resulting in what is being observed:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr>
>     <td>
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> fffff
> ```

You could try to switch [the Lexer to *DirectLex*](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.LexerImpl) and see if that changes the behaviour, but I doubt it - you might be stuck with this behaviour. Give it a whirl, though.